# how can I run grails commands in heroku?

Tags: postgresql, grails, heroku, database-migration

I'm trying to deploy a new grails 2.0.3 app to heroku using the cedar stack. My app is using the [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) to manage the postgres schema. In development I'm able to run grails dbm-update in order to update my schema. In heroku, it seems grails isn't available. Any suggestions?

My current workaround ideas include trying to connect directly to the heroku postgres from my local and run the migration that way (not ideal, and doesn't work w/ shared DB), or perhaps forking the [heroku grails buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-grails) (seems excessive).

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get things moving along by running dbm-update (could be any grails script) directly against prod from my local machine. Here's how:

1. Get the credentials for your heroku pg instance. I think it's only possible to do this w/ a dedicated db, not the shared type. This could be changing with some [very new heroku pg developments](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/5/3/crane_the_new_50_per_month_production_database_/).
2. Create a new environment datasource in your datasource.groovy w/ the prod details. Mine looks something like:

```
 prodadmin {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "none"
            driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            url = 'jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/dbname?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory'
            username = 'user'
            password = 'password'
        }
}
```

With that in place, you can go ahead and update your production grails app's schema in heroku with a command like:

```
 grails -Dgrails.env=prodadmin dbm-update
```

Answer (score 0):

The autorun feature was created for situations like this. See the section "Autorun on start" at http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ in section 4.

Comment: I tried autorun, but had exceptions when inserts from my bootstrap.groovy file were run. I didn't investigate deeply but I suspect that the bootstrap is being run before the autorun happens.